# How to retrieve data from database using entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a database table consists of {EmployeeId,name,city,gender}. i want to retrieve them and show it in the view..but getting the exception of

> "The underlying provider failed on"

My Model:

```
[Table("tblEmployee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

my controller:

```
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{        
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        EmployeeContext employeeContext=new EmployeeContext();
        Employee aEmployee= employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp =>  emp.EmployeeId == id);
        return View(aEmployee);
    }
}
```

global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer<MvcPragim.Models.EmployeeContext>(null);
```

Connectionstring:

```
<add name="EmployeeContext"
     connectionString="Server=ASUS- PC\SQLEXPRESS; Database=mvc_db; User Id=sa; password=1234;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The issue is important..Thnx in advance

Comment: You are not disposing of `employeeContext`.  I suppose that is unrelated because it is a local variable, but you must properly dispose of the context to release resources that it holds.  Use the `using` keyword.

Comment: You receive this error always, or only if call the method parallelly?

Comment: Can you post your connection string? Other questions with the same error have been answered with something incorrect in the connection string....

Comment: please edit the question with code; code in the comments doesn't retain formatting or syntax highlighting.

Comment: `using (EmployeeContext employeeContext=new EmployeeContext()) {
        Employee aEmployee= employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp =>  emp.EmployeeId == id);
        return View(aEmployee); }`

Comment: using doesnt help...shows the same error..@EricJ.

Comment: Is this really all code? It doesn't look it should cause any issue. (I assume the space in the connection string is a typo?).

Comment: the view code is accurate..it cant compile through  Employee aEmployee= employeeContext.Employees.Single(emp =>  emp.EmployeeId == id);
it shows the exception.@GertArnold

Comment: Could you update your post with the call stack ?

Comment: can you post the code of your _OnModelCreating_ method ?

Comment: What??? Why did you remove the exception message? And why don't you post a stack trace as asked before?

Comment: solve me the problem..i am spending the second day on this..cant take this anymore..@GertArnold

Comment: Well, you're not helping yourself by removing information in stead of adding it. I have no clue whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.install the entity framework useing nUGet 
2.the name of the controller and the connectionstring name does not match.Paste the controller name in the connection string.